# Cover letter: work in/work for/work with/work at

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I understand how these work:

- I work in IT.
- I work at Google.
- I work for Google.
- I work with computers.

But how about these? To tell someone if I get this job, I would gain experience.

> 1. I will gain experience by working **in** your firm?
> 2. I will gain experience by working **at** your firm?
> 3. I will gain experience by working **for** your firm?
> 4. I will gain experience by working **with** your firm?

I am not sure quite now. Which of the above are preferred? #4 is slightly less my preference because "with" gives me the implication that I am working in a joint partnership (business-business), although one can argue a worker works with employer.

Comment: If the above are okay, the below ones are also okay! ;)

Comment: @MaulikV Thanks. I guess I should be explicit about the exact context I am looking to solve. You are correct that they are all grammatically correct, but I am looking for the sentence makes more sense.

Comment: I agree with @MaulikV – furthermore, I don’t think any of them make “more sense” than any of the others, and all of them would work fine in the context you describe. There is a slight shift in nuance between **work _for_** and **work _with_**, but that doesn’t mean one is more preferable to the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use "to work for"

According to the [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+for)

**work for** someone

> 1. to be employed by someone

**to work at** remarks the place. You can work at Google's cafeteria and you may be hired by Google but if you want to remark that you're a software engineer, I'd use "to work for".

**to work with**, as you have stated, got a sense of business-business relationship, it seems to denote that you work for a company that has established a temporary partnership with Google.